# how to search for values with sql that contain alphabetical values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently using SQL Server 2008, and i have a list of numbers. There are some that are associated with letters, and I would like to pull only the numbers that are associated with these values. I thought a right statement might work, but I'm kind of a noob, and havent been able to find a way that works.

For example:

```
columnName
==============
12                         
13                         
122b 
11a
10z
9
609
```

I want to view:

```
Result
==============
122b
11a
10z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
WHERE YourColumn like '%[a-z]'
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support regexes directly (it requires a CLR extension), but it's [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28SQL.90%29.aspx) supports ranges:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ISNUMERIC(columnName) = 0
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41187/1)

Other Source(s)

- [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, for those records this will actually work fine. Maybe op should clarify if that is the only pattern for his values